# Nuxt vuex computed getters is not changing

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

The problem is that inside the component, the computed property works, but the same computed property written the same way on the page returns an empty object.

state:

```
export const state = () => ({
  mapAddress: {},
})
```

Getter:

```
  getMapAddress: state => {
    return state.mapAddress
  },

computed: {
 mapAddress() {
    return this.$store.getters.getMapAddress;
 }
}
```

Setter:

```
setMapAddress(state, {id, address}) {
    state.mapAddress[id] = address
  },
```

In component:

```
this.$store.commit("setMapAddress", {
   id: mker.id, 
   address: addressResult
});
```

I think that error cuz need to use this.$set() but how i can use it on nuxt vuex mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setMapAddress(state, { id, address }) {
    this._vm.$set(state.mapAddress, id, address)
},
```

Comment: Instead of this computed property you can use the mapState method from Vuex:

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this computed property you can use the **mapState** method from Vuex:

```js
  import { mapState } from 'Vuex'
```

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      mapAddress: (state) => state.mapAddress
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use mapgetters. try this:

```
computed: {
    
   ...mapGetters({ mapAddress: 'YOUR_STORE_NAME/getMapAddress' })
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it reactive, you need to use `Vue.set` in your setter:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// ...

setMapAddress (state, { id, address }) {
  Vue.set(state.mapAddress, id, address);
},
```